# (TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object) when calling function in Django

Tags: python, django, function, error-handling, typeerror

I'm trying to create a website that takes user text input via a form and returns only the questions from the input. I want to save both the initial user input and the questions to my database each time some input is submitted. I have basically everything taken care of, except I am stuck on this TypeError each time I test the submission of text in the form. Here are the details of the error:

```
Traceback:

File "/Users/joshuablew/Projects/HW/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  39.             response = get_response(request)

File "/Users/joshuablew/Projects/HW/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/Users/joshuablew/Projects/HW/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/Users/joshuablew/Projects/HW/HWapp/v1/views.py" in user_text_view
  20.             user_questions = Question_Init(user_input_obj)

File "/Users/joshuablew/Projects/HW/HWapp/v1/function1.py" in Question_Init
  23.   textList = sent_tokenize(text1)

File "/Users/joshuablew/Projects/HW/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nltk/tokenize/__init__.py" in sent_tokenize
  94.     return tokenizer.tokenize(text)

File "/Users/joshuablew/Projects/HW/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nltk/tokenize/punkt.py" in tokenize
  1237.         return list(self.sentences_from_text(text, realign_boundaries))

File "/Users/joshuablew/Projects/HW/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nltk/tokenize/punkt.py" in sentences_from_text
  1285.         return [text[s:e] for s, e in self.span_tokenize(text, realign_boundaries)]

File "/Users/joshuablew/Projects/HW/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nltk/tokenize/punkt.py" in span_tokenize
  1276.         return [(sl.start, sl.stop) for sl in slices]

File "/Users/joshuablew/Projects/HW/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nltk/tokenize/punkt.py" in <listcomp>
  1276.         return [(sl.start, sl.stop) for sl in slices]

File "/Users/joshuablew/Projects/HW/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nltk/tokenize/punkt.py" in _realign_boundaries
  1316.         for sl1, sl2 in _pair_iter(slices):

File "/Users/joshuablew/Projects/HW/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nltk/tokenize/punkt.py" in _pair_iter
  310.     prev = next(it)

File "/Users/joshuablew/Projects/HW/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nltk/tokenize/punkt.py" in _slices_from_text
  1289.         for match in self._lang_vars.period_context_re().finditer(text):

Exception Type: TypeError at /input/
Exception Value: expected string or bytes-like object
```

Here is the function I am running on the text:

```
import nltk

from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize

from v1 import views


def Question_Init(user_input_obj):

    Beginning_Question_Prompts = ("Who","Whom","What","Where","When","Why","Which",
    "Whose","How","Was","Were","Did","Do","Does","Is")
    Ending_Question_Prompts = ("?",":","...")
    questions = []

    text1 = user_input_obj

    textList = sent_tokenize(text1)

    for sentence in textList:
        if sentence.startswith(Beginning_Question_Prompts):
            questions.append(sentence)

        if sentence.endswith(Ending_Question_Prompts):
            questions.append(sentence)

    return questions
```

Here is my view I'm using to save the input to my database and run my function on the input.

```
def text_input(request):
    form = forms.UserTextForm()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        request:
        form = forms.UserTextForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            user_input = request.POST.get('user_input', '')
            user_input_obj = models.UserText(user_input = user_input)
            user_questions = Question_Init(user_input_obj)
            user_questions.save()

            print(user_questions)


    else:
        form = forms.UserTextForm()

    return render(request, 'text_input_form.html', {'form': form})
```

And my model:

```
class UserText(models.Model):
    user_input = models.CharField(max_length=2000)
```

I don't understand what this error is telling me I need to do. Do I need to convert the user input into a string or byte-type thing? How should I go about doing this? I've also read that I may need to do something with a **unicode**() method in my model. I am not familiar with how to use unicode in this situation. Does unicode have any significance here? Thank you for the help, I appreciate it.

Comment: What I can't understand is what you're doing with those TextInput instances or why you're passing your data to them. Don't do that, and your problem will probably go away.

Comment: @DanielRoseman The TextInput is a model connected to my TextInputForm that receives the user data. Is this not needed?

Comment: OK, well that's a confusing name because it's also the name of a built-in form widget, but never mind. But in your nltk code you are doing something very strange; you ignore the `user_input_obj` object passed to the function, and try and access the field directly via the TextInput class itself, which makes no sense.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Ok, I fixed the naming issue and used `user_input_obj` instead of calling the field from the model. I am still getting this "string or byte-type error" on my server when I input text. Any other ideas?

Comment: You need to show the full traceback.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Just edited them into thread

Comment: Can you update the code of Question_Init after you made the fixes above?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Alright, I updated the whole post with the changes in Questio_Init and the name changes since you said TextInput is also a widget.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're passing the entire UserInput object to the nlkt function, which as the error states is only expecting a string. You could fix this by just passing the relevant field:

```
text1 = user_input_obj.user_input
```

but to be honest I'm confused about why you're creating that model in the first place - it would be simpler to just pass the result of `request.POST.get(...)` to the Question_Init function.

Note also that that function returns a list of sentences, which you then call `save` on - this won't work, as a list doesn't have a save method. Not sure what you are trying to save there.

Comment: This solved the error issue. I added what you had for "text1" and completely got rid of the model instance that doesn't make sense. It got rid of the type error, and then it showed " 'list' object has no attribute 'save' " like you stated. To clarify, I want each question found from the input with my nltk function to be connected within my database to the original user input. I guess this would have to be done with 1 of the 3 relationships in Django. Since they can't be stored as a list, should they be separated individually as strings and then saved?

Comment: Yes, you could have a Sentence class with a foreign key to UserText.

Comment: Sweet, thank you so much for your help. I really appreciate it. I would have been stuck for a while without your pointers